# Rotated Image Print in IE8

Tags: html, css, printing, internet-explorer-8

I have a site that rotates an image using either the CSS3 transforms, or the filter css command. When I go to print the page in IE8, the image does not print out rotated.

Anyway to make that happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868988/printing-webpage-with-rotated-text-in-internet-explorer-9

Comment: It's similar, but not a duplicate. Their issue is with ie9.

Comment: Yes, I know. But is it the same issue?

Comment: It's close, but not a duplicate. For instance, the issue with IE is that it needs the CSS3 codes to stay transformed in the print. IE8 does not support the CSS3 calls, so the filter needs to be used, but on print, the filter is lifted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css 3 transforms are not supported by earlier ie. You would need to use javacript to somewhat replicate the effect

Comment: I'm not using a CSS3 command for the earlier versions of IE, I'm using the filter. However, when you go to print, the filter effect is removed.

Comment: After a bit of research, figured out how to do this with JS.

Comment: @joseph This would be somewhat what you are looking for http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

Comment: @JosephThomasLavoie can you elaborate on your solution to getting the rotated images to print?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with IE8 and got fixed by setting media attribute to style tag as follows.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
```