# Hover image text appears , problems in safari

Tags: jquery, css, browser, cross-browser

http://www.noor-azmi.com/element/projects.html

When u hover the thumbnails , text will appear.

This works just fine in all browser except safari

Can anyone help ? Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

you should add   `-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` to `.middle` and it will work .

also one suggestion : ( i might be wrong about this )

you are using `@media (-webkit-transform-3d)` which is a non standard feature and as MDN says

> Non-standard
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

you should use @supports instead, which has the following syntax

> @supports `<supports-condition>` {
>
> `<group-rule-body>`
>
> }

P.S. never link to external websites, but instead post your code here and replicate the problem . questions like yours are very easily downvoted and closed

Comment: Thanks, I am quite new to stack overflow so i dont know much regarding the rules

Comment: Hi, but when in safari when i hover the image will have an underline and also in IE when hover the text is blue . Why is that ? It does not have problem in firefox and chrome

Comment: I also just found out that it does not work in IE.... any suggestions how to make it work in IE ?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d . //-ms-transform does not exist in IE10+. IE8 and older have no support for CSS transforms, IE9 uses only -ms-transform, and IE10 and newer use only the unprefixed transform. // see here for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969621/css-transform-not-working-ie

Comment: My rule also have unprefixed transform. Why does it still does not work in IE ?

Comment: as i told you in my answer. do not use @media (-webkit-transform-3d) . this ` -webkit-transform-3d is a non-standard boolean CSS media feature whose value indicates whether vendor-prefixed CSS 3D transforms are supported or not. This media feature is only supported by WebKit and Blink. The standards-based alternative is to use a @supports feature query instead. `

Comment: While this might answer the question, linked resources is no good to base answer upon. As soon as that link dies so will the value of this answer and question. I suggest you wait and post answers until there is a proper written question.