# transform: translate Not working across all browsers

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I have an issue.

```
image {
  transform: translate(40px, 40px);
}
```

Isn't working on Internet Explorer 11

**Full Working Code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/f7u38uds/

This is how it looks in in internet explorer 11.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0A6E.png)

Is there something that I can use that will work across all browsers?

Comment: Are you trying to center that circle?

Comment: Yes. So that it works across all browsers.

Comment: Then don't transform translate, what if the size of the canvas/browser increases? Then it won't be centered. Use Flexbox

Comment: It won't increase It stays at one size, all the time.

Comment: This has already been answered. I know you're learning but please check other StackOverflow questions before asking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969621/css-transform-not-working-ie

Comment: Nothing on there refers to internet explorer 11.

Comment: Did you try vendor prefixes?

Comment: Are you the same person as [coding6783](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8769005/coding6783)? Why are you using a different account? This seems a follow on question from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026417/moving-the-circle-image-into-the-middle-without-touching-everything-else#comment81001621_47026822) and the name is rather similar in form.

Comment: The link I sent to you says that transforms are not supported in IE 10+ which includes IE 11. It clearly states this.

Comment: Both these codes work. Which one should I use and why? They are both set up differently. Code 2 https://jsfiddle.net/snu071jj/5/ / Code 3 https://jsfiddle.net/3ppLd3cp/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
image {
  transform: translate(40px, 40px);
  -ms-transform: translate(40px, 40px);
}
```